# Android: keep bitmap in application class

Tags: android, memory-leaks, bitmap

I have big bitmap covering whole screen. After reading a lot of posts about memory leaks and performance I noticed 2 problems:
1. Generating big bmp costs time.
2. Caching big bmp /static bmp in activity/ speeds up activity start, but causes problem with references and memory.

My decision is to move bitmap in Application class.
How will this reflect on references and garbage collection?
Do I have to make bitmap in application class static?

### UPDATE:

Please don't comment 'same memory' in both cases. My question is related to references and garbage collecting.

Answer (score 0):

It's not important how you load bitmap when it is in memory.
It still takes the same amount of memory.

Comment: I'm tinking about references. In some cases they will mess garbage collection.